# MVC 4 Model and ViewBag error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Here i am using MVC 4 as per my hosting provider requirement i cannot use later version 4.5,4.5.1,4.5.2 my issue is in the image provided here
[Three errors in one image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYGuj.jpg)

These three errors are not showing in 4.5,4.5.1 but in this version of 4 it is showing.

As i am trying to publish it in my local disk it shows up the errors on error list tab which is third in the image, first and second are in the code as you see above third. I've deleted and create a new page naming the same but error still shows.

Comment: Can you post the code, you description is not clear

Comment: you don't need to give name to your hidden field it by default will take the same name as of your property or either the hidden field property if it already exist.